# WSO2 identity server with multi tenant mode, unable to add users?

Tags: multi-tenant, wso2-identity-server

I'm evaluating WSO2 Identity server, it was very quick to get started with (thanks for that!).

However I'd like to add support for multi tenancy, but after I have added a new domain I'm not able to add any users to that tenant.

All new users go directly into the carbon.super domain.

Also when adding a tenant I can only select the 'demo' usage plan. I understand that the multi tenancy is available in Stratos Live as SaaS, but I'd like to have it (or at least evaluate it) on a stand alone deployment.

Is that possible and how do I go about to enable it? I did search around and look into the config files but nothing obvious.

Edit: I'm using the embedded LDAP atm. I'm planning on using AWS RDBMS (MySql) at a later time.

Comment: Hi Magnus, did you get an answer elsewhere to your question? Thanks

Comment: No, however I found that the OAuth1/2 provider in the latest WSO2 IDM crashes when I try to make requests to it's endpoint which made me look at other solutions.

Comment: This should be worked, what is the version are you using?

Comment: I was using the latest download on the WSO2 homepage at the time 4.1.0. I did clean installs but got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

1. To configure for RDBMS
   you have to do the following.
   a) Add the data source configuration of your RDBMS  in repository\conf\datasources\master-datasources.xml

   ```
   <datasource>
       <name>MY_IDM_DB</name>
           <description>The datasource used for user manager mydomain.com</description>
           <jndiConfig>
               <name>jdbc/myIDMDB</name>
           </jndiConfig>
           <definition type="RDBMS">
               <configuration>
                   <url>jdbc:postgresql://192.168.210.48:5432/my_db</url>
                   <username>postgres</username>
                   <password>admin123</password>
                   <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
                   <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                   <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                   <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                   <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                   <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
               </configuration>
           </definition>
       </datasource>
   ```

   b) In repository\conf\user-mgt.xml, modify the entries in 
       **jdbc/myIDMDB** This is the datasource you created previously.
         **org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.multitenancy.SimpleRealmConfigBuilder** Previously there was an LDAP config builder, now you are changing to SimpleConfigBuillder.

   c)Comment LDAP User Store and uncomment the JDBC user store in same user-mgt.xml
     
     you can also search for **org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager**
   d) In repository\conf\tenant-mgt.xml, comment TenantManager element and search for **org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager** and uncomment it. Otherwise you can add the following tags.
2. When I tried with both default LDAP and an RDBMS user stores, LDAP as primary user store and RDBMS as secondary user store, an extra property I had to set in RDBMS user store configuration for the domain. 
   **abc.com**
   after this, when I create a user I have to create like abc.com\user1. This user will be saved in my RDBMS database and also, when I loging I have to provide like abc.com\user1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried SCIM user management provided by WSO2. Initially I struggled to create a user under a tenant. Today I am successful to do that.

https://example.com:9443/wso2/scim/Users   (I used Identity Server Version 4.6.0)

**Request**: 
{
  "schemas": [
    "http://wso2.org/claims"
  ],
  "userName": "sunil132@binkam.com",
  "password": "admin12345"
}

**Important thing is**: In authorization header you have to provide tenant's admin.

I gave the above details for your information only.

In your case, you have to login with tenant admin user instead of admin/admin and create user. 
Ex. if your tenant admin user is admin@abc.com you have to login with this id instead of default admin user.